# Indian passport and Canadian resident schengen visa

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, schengen-visas, canadian-residents

I have an Indian passport and an Canadian resident PR. I want to apply for my schengen visa while I am on a visit to India (impromptu backpacking plan). Is it strictly not advisable (or high chances of rejection) to atleast try to apply while i am in India? is it worth a shot? Any others who had similar scenario?

Thanks! cheers!

Comment: You can try.  If your application is unsuccessful, it should be "rejected" rather than "refused," meaning that you've applied to the wrong consulate and your application was not evaluated on its merits.  The visa fee would be refunded to you, but I suspect that the third-party processing fee would not be.  Without a compelling reason for why you were unable to apply in Canada (and "impromptu plans" are not compelling unless you've been away from Canada since more than three months before you plan to go to the Schengen area), you're unlikely to succeed.

Comment: Also i checked with the third party (VFS global) and they have a criteria "one can apply only if they are present in same area for past 6 months min". There is also an option to apply directly to the german consulate, but i suspect it being succesful. I should have looked into these stipulations beforehand and it would have been much easier to apply in Canada. But one learns from his mistakes :) Thanks a lot again and hope this thread helps others. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Germany is **allowed** to give you a visa if *they* accept that it would be a hardship for you to apply from your usual place of residence. They are **not required** to consider your application.
- You would submit supporting evidence of your finances and ties to your homeland. This is *Canada* and the visa officials in India would be at a disadvantage to evaluate it.
- There is no significant illegal immigration from Canada to Germany. It is to your advantage if they look at you as a Canadian resident rather than an Indian citizen when you are both.